# Gnuplot multiplot ignoring y=1

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use multiplot to plot two data sets of the form

```
1  1 - 3 -  
2  - 2 - 5  
3  4 - 7 -   
4  - 8 - 2  
5  3 - 6 -
```

However, when I use p "data.txt" u 1:2 etc. the data are seemingly plotted twice, shifted with respect to each other. What is the proper syntax for ignoring y=0 data within multiplot?

Comment: Do not use `multiplot` if you want to draw multiple plot elements into a single coordinate system. Also, why do you want to ignore `y=0` data? Your data set doesn't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise? If I run the script

```
$data <<EOD
1  1 - 3 -  
2  - 2 - 5  
3  4 - 7 -   
4  - 8 - 2  
5  3 - 6 - 
EOD

plot for [i=2:5] $data u 1:i w lp pt 7 title "".i
```

with gnuplot 5.0.6 I get the following image, which is exactly what I expect. All points with `-` are ignored:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Christoph, that looks good. But I have a multiplot with something similar to the following:  
    y1=0; y2=10; y3=8; y4=11  
    set multiplot  
    set yrange [y1:y2]  
    p "data1.txt"  and then set yrange [y3:y4]    p "data2.txt"